# php with apache and xampp

Tags: php, ajax.beginform

i want to test my skills with php on 'localhost' with the php embedded in the 'page' ie

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>test stuff</title>
  <style>  </style>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
  
</head>

<body>
<button id="b2" onclick="do_post()">post</button>

<script>
console.log("it begins");

// --- send a message to myself ---  
function do_post()
{
  console.log("at do_post()");
  var arr = {"client": "fredi", "action": "mod", "rix": 6, "row": "yarn|white|5.59@"};
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'aaaaa.php',
    data: arr,
    //success: success,
    //dataType: dataType
  })
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
<?php
var_dump($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]);
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET')
{
  echo ("caught GET");
  var_dump($_GET);
}
else
{
  echo ("caught POST");
  var_dump($_POST);
}
?>
```

I know that the php is getting executed because i catch the 'GET' request to load the page because i see ...
string(3) "GET" caught GETarray(0) { }

i looked at the .ini files but all i saw was "IF YOU DONT KNOW WHAT YOU'RE DOING STAY OUT"

I suspect that it is my 'localhost' server preventing me from harming my machine but i don't know that for sure.

Help please i am 84.7 yrs old and have been programming since 1960 but have had brain injury and am trying to keep it active.

Comment: I'm not clear on what's being asked? ... are you getting an error or is there some other situation? ... open the browser's developer tools window (Ctrl+Shift+i) to the Console tab before clicking the post button to ensure that no javascript errors are occurring, and among the other tabs in the developer tools is the Network tab where you can see the ajax request ... and is `aaaaa.php` a real file? No problem assisting, just need more info.

Answer (score 0):

I like to keep a small footprint and so append the php to the html page, after the  tag. I am writing a small store inventory monitor and the inventory is a dot-txt file. When i CRUD an item i want to tell the server what and where so that the 'database' is current. The PHP i have appended sees the initial GET sent by the browser to load the page. When I $.POST() or $.GET() to the same URL as the running page i dont see it.  I am wondering if it is a 'localhost' issue or piss-poor programming on my part. wie when the browser sends a 'GET' i see it, when my code sends a 'GET' i dont.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).